# Haskell factorial implementation

Tags: haskell

I implemented `factorial` like below.

```
factorial n = n * factorial(n-1)
factorial 0 = 1
```

Unfotunately above code throws

> C stack overflow

Then I changed the code like this:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial(n-1)
```

And it finally succeeded.
Can anybody let me know the difference between first code and second code?

Comment: Keep warnings enabled with `-Wall`: GHC should warn you that in the first case the second equation is redundant, hinting at the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You provided two cases:

```hs
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
factorial 0 = 0
```

When you try `factorial 0`, Haskell will attempt to match `0` to each of your two cases, starting from the top case. Since the case `n` matches with `0` (and in fact matches with absolutely anything), you will always be using the top line and it will be as if you had only written

```hs
factorial n = n * factorial (n - 1)
```

On the other hand, if you reverse the order, Haskell will try to match `0` with `0` first and will thus trigger the `factorial 0 = 1` case.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern matching using `n`in the first definition supersedes the literal `0` in the second pattern. Haskell will match based on order. Since `n` matches any number (including `0`) you never get to that base case of `0`.

The second definition alleviates that mistake.